# ASP Core WebApi: Single setup to format all query parameters snake_case

Tags: asp.net-core, facebook-c#-sdk, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Let's assume I have this simple controller action

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get([FromQuery] Query query)
{
    // Return filtered weather forecasts...
}
```

...and this `Query` model:

```cs
public class Query
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int TotalDays { get; set; } = 7;
}
```

Now, the request path looks like: `/weatherforecast?City=Berlin&TotalDays=3`

**How can I introduce a general configuration to format all *PascalCase* model properties / *camelCase* action parameters written in C# into *snake_case* query parameters requesting by the consumer**:
`/weatherforecast?city=Berlin&total_days=3`

---

By the way,

- My `Startup.ConfigureServices(..)` uses `services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);`
- I've already read https://medium.com/@xsoheilalizadeh/snake-case-query-string-in-asp-net-core-25fc2d7bdab0
  ...very cumbersome :-(

Comment: What's the issue now sir? The document you provided above doesn't work? And did you mean that you wanna the user always type snake_case parameters in the request url but you wanna the variables in your code not in snake_case? Sorry for can't know your requirement well and could you pls describe it more clearly?

Comment: @TinyWang I concretized my question. And of course I don't write snake_case in C#: Any tool like ReSharper, SonarQube, ... would complain about + I don't want to!

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such easy configuration to realize your goal. It's more likely to need you to write some custom code to achieve that. Is it necessary for you to use snake_case here?

Comment: @TinyWang Yes, unfortunately we're forced to ensure kebab-case for the request path and snake_case for query parameter names :-(

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a middleware to achieve in single place

```
 public class SnakeCaseQueryStringMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public SnakeCaseQueryStringMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;

        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.Query.Any(q => q.Key.Contains("_")))
            {
                var queryitems = httpContext.Request.Query.SelectMany(x => x.Value, (col, value) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(col.Key, value)).ToList();
            
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryparameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                foreach (var item in queryitems)
                {
                    var key = SnakeToPascalCase(item.Key);
                    KeyValuePair<string, string> newqueryparameter = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, item.Value);
                    queryparameters.Add(newqueryparameter);
                }

                var qb1 = new QueryBuilder(queryparameters);
                httpContext.Request.QueryString = qb1.ToQueryString();
            }

            await _next(httpContext);
        }

               string SnakeToPascalCase(string input) => System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input.Replace("_", " ")).Replace(" ", "");

    }
```

Then you need to register it in Startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
     //Support Snake Case QueryString
            app.UseMiddleware<SnakeCaseQueryStringMiddleware>();
    }
```